# Lost changes in TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

On Commit found many conflicts in files after taking latest, so I remove mapping thinking remap somewhere else and paste my old local changes in latest version of TFS but remove mapping remove all files with my latest changes.
I have remapping my code somewhere but please help me that how I can find my old changes

Comment: next time please take your time to format your question, this will help a lot helping you... Concerning your problem: When you changed your mapping and pressed "get latest", you probably have deleted your files that where not checked in, thus deleting your work, sorry to say so. In the future, simply do the conflict resolution or press "keep mine" for all files and afterwards "merge" using the "compare with latest" feature [not recommended, you may miss something that WAS checked in!]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will keep in mind for all future questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't resolved for conflict, but just remove mapping and bind again for somewhere else,
but after remapping binding again to my original first path no loss I found there, 
all checked out files were remain same...

might be helpful for others